# Capturing email address using regex in html text format

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, regex, email

i am new to regex. I am trying to capture email addresses using python in html text form.

```
<html>
<b>To:</b> staff@hr.com<br>
<b> From:</span>john@hr.com&gt<br>
</html>
```

my expected output is

```
<html>
<b>To:</b>xxx<br>
<b> From:</span>xxx&gt<br>
</html>
```

my regex for email is "^[^@]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.*-]+\.+[a-z.*-]+$"

im running the codes below:

```
email_pattern = "^[^@]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\\.+[a-z._-]+$"

re.sub(email_pattern, "XXX", string)
```

But it is not working.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
email_pattern = "^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$"
```

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Turns out the regex for email doesn't capture all types of email.